# How can I make html page which works fine on web and mobile apps

Tags: html, responsive-design

I am building html pages which can have text, pictures, videos, facebook like buttons etc. I am using CKeditor to create pages. I store that html in database and then access it for web and mobile applications.

It works fine for web but not for apps. Sometimes problem with videos, pictures, width, height etc and quality is also not good on apps. If I fix things for mobile apps then web disturb. HTML5 support mobile environment but how can I get one html for all environments?

I don't want to create seperate html for all environments, I want to create one html and it should work for all environments. Anyone can suggest some best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) as @Smokescreen suggested.

You can use these directly within your stylesheets and include the stylesheet on the page the same way as normal, but additionally by adding a `media` attribute to a `link` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css" />
```

Or with inline CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .button {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

It will take some time to get your website to look perfect on all devices though. I'd suggest thinking about if it's even worth spending so much time modifying your website just so it looks good on mobile etc. For example, why bother adapting a website about retirement homes when you know that the target audience (old people) will barely ever be visiting your website on a mobile device. You haven't specified what your website is about, so it's up to you to do your research and decide on this.

Another option is redesigning your website and using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). This option may seem a little over the top, but you'd be suprised how quickly you can build decent looking websites with bootstrap which are fully responsive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Media queries, view port tag

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px){
      /* iPads  ----------- */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
      /* smartphones**/
}
```

Meta tag into header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=no;"/>
```

Use percentage in height / width, fonts
You also need to know UI properties in java for webview like margin, padding etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add any CSS to style it differently depending upon the screen size of the device that is opening the page.

eg make yourself a css stylesheet and then use media queries to define different styles for use with different size browser windows. Then in the 'source' code view of ckeditor assign different ids or classes to your html text such that they then take the styling from the stylesheet for use at different screen sizes.

This way you can say something like - for a screen resolution of 1024px or above style the text at 25px etc etc, for a screen of 600px or less style the text at 12px etc etc. You can also use this method to recofigure your layout for different screens.